# Why don't I need references for a non visual studio c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When developing a C# applications in Visual Studio, I need to add a reference to the library I want to make use of before I can import it into the application with the `using` keyword.

If I don't use Visual Studio, I can import libraries without having to add a reference to them first. Really my question has two points:

- Why can't C# just import the libraries manually in Visual Studio (its clearly capable of working this way)?
- What does adding a reference do for a project?, surely it can either find the library or it can't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in the same directory as `csc.exe`, you'll find a file called `csc.rsp`. That lists all the references which are effectively automatically added. The C# compiler still needs to know what to look for - but it has a great big default list.

If you use the [`/noconfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hww4s6c.aspx) flag then you'll see the same behaviour as with Visual Studio - every reference has to be listed explicitly.

As for what adding a reference does to a project: it tells the C# compiler to use that library. That's all. Note that `using` directives are to do with *namespaces*, not *assemblies*. They're often named the same, but they're completely separate concepts. A `using` directive does **not** "import" a library - it just instructs the C# compiler to look for members within that namespace when resolving names.

Comment: For reference, you can find that directory as `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\$VERSION` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\$VERSION`. Although it seems that its in the `v3.5` rather than `v4`.